# Matchmaking algorithm for a game

Tags: c++, algorithm

(This is for a game I am designing) Lets say that there are 2 teams of players in a game. Each team will have 4 players. Each player has a rank(0-9), where 0 indicates a bad player and 9 indicates an amazing player. There is a queue (or list) of players who are waiting to play a game (This could be a small number or a very large number). Lets say that each teams' overall rank is an average of the 4 players within in. There are multiple open games and teams where a player can be placed.

Question: What is a good algorithm that places a player in the waiting queue/list on a team so that each team in a game will have more or less the same overall rank in a game (Does not have to be perfect)? Also, the players should not have to wait more than a minute to be placed on a team(Can be more if very little players) [The faster they are placed, the better]

Comment: Sounds like a weighted queue dispatch. 
You are going to need to define "more or less overall" , least- squares, inverse-sum-of-inverse, eliptical, what?

Comment: Wait time is a function of arrival rate, number of games, length of games and player rating distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start to build the table with one person.  If person A has a rank of 8, and another player joins the game with a rank of 4, and your placement guide is a factor of 2, then

Player A has the table
Player A has a rank of 8

Player B enters the room
Does player B not have a rank between 6 & 10?

```
if (Brank < Arank - 2 || Brank > Arank + 2)
```

If that is true, then the rank is not within the limits of the table and you should start a new table with Brank as the rank you compare to.

If that is false, then the rank is +- 2 of the table's declared rank and that player can join.

If you really want to get fancy, you can declare the ranking based on the number of people waiting for a table.

If 100 people in lobby, make the limit +- 2.
If 15 people in lobby, make the limit +- 4. (make it more uneven game, but will not cause people to wait as long).

Answer (score 8):

This completely depends on how closely the teams's combined rankings need to be.  If accuracy isn't that important, you can do something simple like this:

1. Take the first eight players off of the list.
2. Place highest-ranking player on team A and second-highest on team B
3. There are six players remaining, which means you have 20 team combinations left.  Calculate all 20 and choose the combination that leads to the closest team scores.

This should be fast and simple, although it probably won't produce the most balanced results.  Wait times should be minimal because it always uses the players who have been waiting the longest.  Step 2 is really a shortcut to eliminate the number of possibilities to calculate.  Without step 2, there are 70 possible team combinations ("8 choose 4").  You may find that you can calculate all 70 and find a good solution without taking up too much time.  Hint: the ideal team score is (sum of all players / 2).  If you stumble across a combination with that particular team score, you can stop.

You can refine this a step further if you'd like.  Once you find the best possible matchup of the eight, compare the two team scores.  If they are too far apart (you'd have to define what constitutes "too far"), replace two players at random with the next two on the queue and try again.  You can even make the definition of "too far" become more lenient based on how long a player has been waiting.

You can also take a slightly different approach to this.  Group players into teams randomly, and then look for two teams that have similar rankings (which becomes as simple as comparing a single number).  Once a team has gone a specified amount of time without finding a match, return those players to the pool to be re-formed into new teams.  If you typically have a large number of players queued (thus a larger pool of ready-made teams), then this might give results faster.

Before you spend too much time on this algorithm, take a good look at the algorithm that generates the player ranking.  Human skill and experience can't be summarized in a single digit without a relatively large margin of error.  If the error here is likely to be reasonably large, then you can afford to have a less-accurate team building algorithm (any extra accuracy would be nullified by the error in the player ranking system).

Comment: I up-voted you for "any extra accuracy would be nullified by the error in the player ranking system."

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this depends on how you measure player skill. There are multiple ways of doing it and each have its own measure for "average skill" of multiple players.

A good approach would be adopting a system already developed, Elo ratings (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) are widely used these days, but know that a straightforward implementation won't work very well if you want to measure individual player skills on a team with multiple players.

That being said, suppose you have a system where the rating of a team is the average of it's members rating. Also, let's suppose players are uniformly distributed among skill levels. A good first approach would be grouping players with the same skill level in the same game. A match where a team has 2 9-rating and 2 1-rating players, and the other has 4 5-rating is not gonna be a good one.

So start grouping players with close skill levels into multiple up-to-8-people groups. (A player could possibly be in more than one of these). You could do this by making groups of players from skill levels 1-4, another for 2-5, 3-6, etc. When any of these groups has 8 players, you can arrange them into a match, and sort the teams in a way that each one has about the same average.

Now, there's the problem of players waiting too long, so you could make a player of skill 4 join player groups of skill level 5-8 if he has waited more than 1 minute e.g. Also keep in mind that the skill ranges covered by the player groups should vary with the number of players in your queue.

Answer (score 1):

Given you have a small finite number of player ranks, you can build your algorithm around that.  Have 10 queues, one for each rank.  Keep track of when each entry was inserted, so you know at all times who the player of rank i that has been waiting the longest is (by inspecting the head of queue i).

From there you can form a game as follows.

1. Take the four perople waiting the longest, form them into a team.
2. Get the total T of their rank
3. Iterate through every 4-partitioning of T, (i,j,k,l) - inspecting the heads of the queues i,j,k,l and adding their waittimes, find the four people waiting the longest in total with a total rank of T.  Form them into the second team and start match.
4. (If none found on step 3, either wait (better matching) or expand search to [T-delta, T+delta] (fairer wait-time))

A 4-partiioning of an integer T is (i,j,k,l) such that i+j+k+l = T.

Answer (score 1):

Measuring player skill is a separate topic I will not give any ideas for. Using an existing scheme (e.g. ELO or the Microsoft research developed formulas http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueSkill or one of the many others) I think is a good starting point.

Once you have your magic number, a lot of considerations come in, as to your (and your players) preferences. While it is not written in C++, below you can find my mini-prototype of a matchmaking system (100 lines of f# code, you can play with on http://www.tryfsharp.org/Create without downloading any tools).

My design goals were:

- Make it run fast (no long iterations for improvements of the team balance), given that there might be 100000 players, of which a few hundred in the queue, to be assigned to maybe 50-100 games to be started, getting too scientific is maybe not a good idea. But I rather see it as a experimental framework and the function you can place your improvements / ideas into is called "ImproveTeams".
- Make no attempt to optimize across multiple new games to be started at a given time.
- Try to give players a gaming experience at their own skill level, by not staffing teams with absolute newbies and pro-gamers alike.

How it works:

- The pool is sorted descending by player rating.
- Top down (best players to worse players), teams are assembled by simply splicing the top 2 N (N = number of players per team). Doing this, results in Team A being always better or equally strong as Team B.
- Call ImproveTeams with the information of team a, team b and the remainder of the pool. ImproveTeams iterates both teams, computes the skill delta, and then depending on whether it is a positive or negative number shuffles the players on the same position in the arrays of both teams.

The same could be applied to the players remaining in the pool, after the first match is paired, until the server capacity (free game-slots) is exhausted or the player pool is empty.

Drawbacks: Bad players have longer waiting times as they are always handled last. An easy modification could improve that by simply alternating between the above depicted algorithm working top down with a dual solution which works bottom up.

```
type Rating = uint32
type RatingDiff = int32
type Player = { name : string; rating : Rating }

// tuple of:  Candidate player in team a, Canditate players in team b, Remainder of pool
type WorkingSet = Player array * Player array * Player array

let pool : Player array = 
    [|  { name = "Hugo"; rating = 1100u }
        { name = "Paul"; rating = 800u }
        { name = "Egon"; rating = 1800u }
        { name = "John"; rating = 1300u }
        { name = "Rob"; rating = 400u }
        { name = "Matt"; rating = 1254u }
        { name = "Bruce"; rating = 2400u }
        { name = "Chuck"; rating = 2286u }
        { name = "Chuck1"; rating = 2186u }
        { name = "Chuck2"; rating = 2860u }
        { name = "Chuck3"; rating = 1286u }
        { name = "Chuck4"; rating = 786u }
    |]

let SortByRating (pool : Player array) : Player array =
    pool 
    |> Array.sortWith 
        (fun (p1 : Player) (p2 : Player) -> 
            match (p1.rating,p2.rating) with 
            | (r1,r2) when r1 > r2 -> -1 
            | (r1,r2) when r1 < r2 -> 1 
            | _ -> 0 
        )

let evens n = 2 * n 
let odds n = 2 * n + 1

// Note: Since the input is sorted by player level, obviously team A is always stronger or equal in strength to team B
let Split (n : int) (a : Player array) : WorkingSet =
    let teamA : Player array = [| for i in 0 .. (n-1) -> a.[evens i] |]
    let teamB : Player array = [| for i in 0 .. (n-1) -> a.[odds i] |]
    let remainder = Array.sub a (2*n) ((Array.length a) - 2 * n)
    ( teamA, teamB, remainder )

 // This is the function where teams get improved - can be as well a recursive function.
 // Anyone is invited to provide alternate, better implementations!
let ImproveTeams (ws : WorkingSet) : WorkingSet =
    let a,b,r = ws
    let R2RD (r : Rating) : RatingDiff =
       let r1 : RatingDiff =  int32 r
       r1
    let UpdateScore (score : RatingDiff) (pa : Player) (pb : Player) : RatingDiff =
        score + (R2RD pa.rating) - (R2RD pb.rating) 
    let improved : RatingDiff * Player array * Player array =
        Array.fold2 
            (fun s pa pb ->
                let score,teamA, teamB = s
                let betterPlayer p1 p2 =
                    match (p1.rating,p2.rating) with
                    | (r1,r2) when r1 >= r2 -> p1
                    | _ -> p2
                let worsePlayer p1 p2 =
                    match (p1.rating,p2.rating) with 
                    | (r1,r2) when r1 >= r2 -> p2
                    | _ -> p1
                let bp = betterPlayer pa pb
                let wp = worsePlayer pa pb
                match score with
                | x when x > 0 -> (UpdateScore x wp bp, Array.append teamA [| wp |], Array.append teamB [| bp |])
                | _ -> (UpdateScore score bp wp, Array.append teamA [| bp |], Array.append teamB [| wp |]) 
             ) (0, [||], [||]) a b
    let ns,nta,ntb = improved
    (nta, ntb,r)    

let rec CreateTeams (maxPlayersPerTeam : int) (players : Player array) : WorkingSet =
    let sortedPool = SortByRating players
    match (Array.length sortedPool) with
    | c when c >= (maxPlayersPerTeam * 2) ->
        Split maxPlayersPerTeam sortedPool
        |> ImproveTeams            
    | 0 -> ( [||], [||], [||] )
    | _ -> CreateTeams (maxPlayersPerTeam-1) players    

let ShowResult (result : WorkingSet) : unit =
    let ShowPlayer p =
        printf "%s - %d" p.name p.rating
    let a,b,r = result
    let Score (pl : Player array) : Rating =
        Array.fold (fun s p -> s + p.rating) 0u pl
    printfn "Team A\t\t\t| Team B"
    Array.iter2 
        ( fun pa pb -> 
            ShowPlayer pa 
            printf "\t\t\t| " 
            ShowPlayer pb
            printfn ""
        ) a b
    let sa = Score a
    let sb = Score b
    printfn "Score Team A: %d\t\t\t| Score Team B: %d" sa sb
    printfn "Players still in pool: "
    Array.iter
        (fun p -> 
            ShowPlayer p
            printfn ""
        ) r

CreateTeams 4 pool |> ShowResult
```

Comment: CreateTeams has a small bug - who can see it? ;) Tip: It only bugs if the pool is smaller than  2 times the size of a team.