# Best way to implement matchmaking queue for a competitive game

Tags: algorithm, game-development, matchmaking

what is the best way to implement a matchmaking queue?

In the game im making, matches have 10 players. Players can be in parties of up to 4 other players. A party has a matchmaking score (integer) that approximates the average skill level of the players in the party.
I don't want players to be in the queue for too long, but I want the matches to be as fair as possible.

This is my current implementation (pseudocode)

```
let gamequeue = binary heap of parties
// ... gamequeue will be populated by parties that join the queue

fn matchmake(gamequeue):
convert gamequeue to a sorted vector
let potential_games = BinaryHeap<Game>
for i in (0, gamequeue.size())
  let potential_game = Game
  // Greedily choose parties
  for j in (i, gamequeue.size())
    // Stop making the game if the player already has 10 players or if party j's matchmaking score
    // is too large compared to party i. Reach is calculated based on the time the party has
    // been in the queue. Note that since the parties are in a binary heap there is a break because
    // all the next parties will exceed gamequeue[i]'s matchmaking score + its reach.
    if gamequeue[j]'s matchmaking score > gamequeue[i]'s matchmaking score + gamequeue[i]'s reach, break
    if the game has 10 players, break
    // If adding this party will exceed 10 players, try adding the next party
    if adding the party would make the game go over 10 players, continue
    add the party to potential_game
  if potential_game has 10 players, add to potential_games
  if potential_game does not have 10 players, continue
// At this point, potential_games will be populated with games sorted by a value "fairness".
// How fairness is calculated is irrelevant to this question
// Note that the first game in potential_games must be valid.
let finished_parties = HashSet<Party>
while potential_games isnt empty
  let f = pop front of potential_games
  for parties in f check if they are in finished_parties
  if all parties in f are not in finished_parties, the game is valid! start that game
  if there exists at least one party in f that is in finished_parties, continue; // skip this potential game
  add the parties in f to finished_parties and remove those parties from the gamequeue
```

The runtime of my matchmaking algorithm is O(n^2).

Is there a better way to structure a matchmaking queue? Or is there a way to speed up my algorithm?

Since the size of parties can vary, I don't think its possible to do something like a sliding window. I feel like any dynamic programming solution would probably be slower than my "greedy"-ish solution.

Comment: Both stable marriage approach Heap and bipartite matching is order of n^2 ... greedy means not fair :) ...

Comment: Maybe I am Wrong or people have better solution than mine ... My soln ( 2*N*N) Run stable marriage once with their score and make best pair and then create a score for the pair as avg of both the score. Now run the stable marriage again to make the Quad with the best avg match ( you may tweak this to make it O(N^2).... If you do greedily people like me playing your game and if I am at level 3 matched with level 7 or 8 ( Clash Royale issue )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989421/matchmaking-algorithm-for-a-game.  There are many algorithms & research paper to do it you may find a Reddit thread on it as well

Comment: Can you assume that potential players arrive fairly quickly? If so, then algorithm performance and good game matches matter more than matching as quickly as possible.

Comment: priority queue === min heap